# Not printed state in React Native

Tags: react-native, state

I'm now using React Native. Now I'm trying to print out one of states that are initialized ( for instance, showText herein ). When I recall this value in render, it doesn't show up ( blank ). The way that I recall is "{this.state.showText}". It doesn't produce any error messages.

Maybe because of the same reason, the initial value of TouchableHighlight seems to be blank. I'm completely lost here since a sample app in Facebook Github works fine within the website. Please give me any idea on this matter.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  ListView,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';


class Greeting extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello {this.props.name}! {this.props.date}~ Class can be added..{'\n'}</Text>
    );
  }
} 
class Test1 extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showText: 'true',
      showTextBool: true,
      wow: 'ddsdfasdf'
    };

  }

  onSignupPress(){
    return "hello";
  }

  render() {

    let display = this.state.showTextBool ? 'true' : 'false';

    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native! {this.state.showText} {this.state.showTextBool}
          {this.state.wow}
        </Text>


        <TextInput style={styles.searchInput} value={this.state.wow} placeholder='Search via name or postcode'/>


        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Go</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>


        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          {display} + {this.onSignupPress()} + {this.state.showText}
        </Text>

      </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },

  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },

  button: {
    height: 36,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    backgroundColor: '#48BBEC', 
    borderColor: '#48BBEC', 
    borderWidth: 1, 
    borderRadius: 8, 
    marginBottom: 10, 
    alignSelf: 'stretch', 
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },

  searchInput: {
    height: 36,
    padding: 4, marginRight: 5,
    flex: 4,
    fontSize: 18, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#48BBEC', borderRadius: 8, color: '#48BBEC'
  }

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Test1', () => Test1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in react native express page. It renders one "true", but you are expected two (the text and the boolean). In the  following part:

```
Welcome to React Native! {this.state.showText} {this.state.showTextBool}
```

The text is being rendered properly (it says indeed 'true'), but the boolean is not there, mainly because you cannot render a boolean like that. Try with the following:

```
{String(this.state.showTextBool)}
```

This will render the boolean value properly.